# Finding closest value to a target in BST, but running into variable referenced before assignment, even though I have covered all cases?

Tags: python, recursion

I am writing code to solve the following problem: we are given a **binary search tree**, and a **target integer value**. Our task is to find the closest value in the BST to this target.

Here is my code:

```
def findClosestValueInBst(tree, target,):
    return findClosestValueInBstHelper(tree, target, float("inf"))

def findClosestValueInBstHelper(tree, target,closest):
    if tree.value == target: 
        return target
    if not tree:
        return closest
    closer = min(abs(target - tree.value), closest)
    if abs(target - tree.value)<closest:
        output = tree.value
    if tree.value<target and tree.right: 
        return findClosestValueInBstHelper(tree.right,target,closer)
    elif tree.value>target and tree.left:
        return findClosestValueInBstHelper(tree.left, target, closer)
    
    elif tree.value<target and not tree.right: 
        if abs(target-tree.value)<closest:
            return tree.value
    elif tree.value>target and not tree.left: 
        if abs(target-tree.value)<closest:
            return tree.value
    return output
```

Now my code passes half of the tests cases but fails the other half, and I run into the error `'output referenced before assignment'` for the final line- I do know what this means; that the code is returning `output` before it is assigned to anything, however I thought that in my code above this line I have covered all possible scenarios and 'output' will be equal to a value.

Any ideas why I am running into this error?

Comment: it means that `output = tree.value` was not executed so `return output` raised this error.

Comment: Thanks Balderman, but that is the issue- I can't see why it is not executing. Because the conditional for it to execute is "if abs(target - tree.value)<closest:" , and this should be true from the getgo, because closest was initialised as float("inf")

Comment: Add a `print` in order to see if it was executed.